# What'the meaning of "break and run"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, verbs

What is the meaning of break in this sentence "he'd broke and run".
For the context: it's a boy bullying by three other boys. They holding him to hurting him. When one of the bullies " break and run".
Is this means that the bully couldn't take it anymore and he ran away maybe because he was scared.
Thanks

Comment: He must have let go of the hold (broke away) and ran off.

Comment: Or that the bully saw an adult coming and broke (let go, in this context, perhaps) and ran. Or the bully's *will* to hurt people broke. It depends on context. E.G., "Faced with the evidence, the criminal broke and confessed."

Comment: The author (or speaker) may have applied a term from a different context in a fairly unrelated sense. The collocation *break and run* is used in games like billiards to mean that a player in a single turn “breaks” (knocks apart the initially tightly grouped balls) and then “runs” (proceeds to knock some or all of those disturbed balls into the pockets).